# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not load

Tags: java, tesseract

I got the following exception when tessaract ocr is used. What is the reason behind this exception?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at tess4j.example.Ocreg.main(Ocreg.java:31)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java code wants to use a native library at runtime (that is what JNI is for).

You must ensure that a correct version of the library is available in the location that it is being looked for.   Note that this can be a bit tricky and the documentation should be followed to the letter.